# ACE Library in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ace, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to build ACE 6.4.8 under Ubuntu 20.04.

I get the following message

```
/ACE_wrappers/ace/os_include/os_stropts.h:56:17: fatal error: stropts.h: No such file or directory
   56 | #  include /**/ <stropts.h>
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [/home/ap1/Projects/ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/rules.local.GNU:189: .shobj/ACE.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ap1/Projects/ACE_wrappers_6_4_8/ace'
make: *** [GNUmakefile:777: ACE] Error 2
```

My understanding is stropts.h header file are part of the posix C lbrary and have been removed from glibc.

Is there any work around here to compile ACE properly?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to changes in Ubuntu 20.04 which is recent, the ACE version you are using is old. Please upgrade to ACE 6.5.9 which you can download from [github](https://github.com/DOCGroup/ACE_TAO/releases/tag/ACE%2BTAO-6_5_9), that includes the necessary [fix](https://github.com/DOCGroup/ACE_TAO/pull/939).

Comment: I proceeded as suggested above and installed ACE 6.5.9
I got this message 
ACE_TkReactor will not be built due to the following disabled make macros: tk

ACE_XtReactor will not be built due to the following disabled make macros: x11 xt

Any suggestion here

Comment: That are just informational messages, when you haven't explicitly enabled xt/x11 these reactors are not compiled

Comment: Thanks a lot for the above.
One last question I dont seem to get QtReactor to compile.
Qt5.9.5 is installed.
This is the content of QtReactor folder

-rw-r--r-- 1 ap1 ap1  522 May  1 16:01 ace_qt4reactor.mpc
-rw-r--r-- 1 ap1 ap1  495 May  1 16:01 ace_qt5reactor.mpc
-rw-r--r-- 1 ap1 ap1 2.2K May  1 16:01 ACE_QtReactor_export.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 ap1 ap1  229 May  1 16:01 ACE_QtReactor.pc.in
-rw-r--r-- 1 ap1 ap1  20K May  1 16:01 QtReactor.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 ap1 ap1 7.7K May  1 16:01 QtReactor.h